# Posting Leads from MSSQL database to another site using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server

I looking to post leads from my MSSQL database to a third party site. I've created a page that queries the database and inserts values into form fields so that I can manually press a submit button. That code is at the bottom.

That's as far as I got before getting stuck on a few things.

1) I need to automate the process. I believe I got this covered using this

```
<script language="JavaScript">
document.frm.submit();
</script>
```

2) The biggest issue I'm facing is running this through a batch of leads. I believe I need a different way of querying the data and submitting it.

I believe I can achieve this by using something similar to this:

```
<?php
var actionForm = $('<form>', {'action': 'thirdpartypage.com', 'method': 'post'}).append($('<input>', {'name': 'action', 'value': 'delete', 'type': 'hidden'}), $('<input>', {'name': 'id', 'value': 'some_id', 'type': 'hidden'}));
actionForm.submit();
?>
```

Now here is what I currently have that query's the database and fills in the form for manual submission.

```
<?php

$myServer = 'someserver';
$myUser = 'someuser';
$myPass = 'somepassword';
$myDB = 'mydb';

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

//select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
  or die("Couldn't open database $myDB"); 

//declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = "Select * From MyTableName WHERE LeadSent=0";

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mssql_query($query);

$row = mssql_fetch_array($result)
//display the results

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- form to display record from database -->
<form name="form" method="POST" action="https://thirdpartysite.com" onSubmit="return validate_form ( );">
<input type="text" name="FirstName" value="<?php echo $row[FirstName]?>"/> <br>
<input type="text" name="LastName" value="<?php echo $row[LastName]?>"/> <br>
<input type="submit"  value="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I could really use some resources or help with this process. I've done what I could with searching through Google, but with my limited knowledge of PHP, I'm having a hard time with adapting examples that I've found into my code.

Answer (score 0):

Change you form field to `FirstName[]`,`LastName[]` etc this will let php place all the inputs into their respective arrays.

Within php then loop through the array adding each set of values into the database.